# How do I change the _Click() event on a MS Access Form?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am hoping to be able to streamline my UI.  I want to have a set of command buttons change the _On_Click() event based on a user selection.  For example:

Main topic selections: cmd1:"Membership Reports", cmd2: "Administration Reports", cmd3: "Other Reports - TBD"

If the user selects cmd1 then the subtopic buttons properties change to allow the user to open reports in that category.

Sub Topic Selections: cmd4: "All Members", cmd5: "Active Members", etc.

If the user selects cmd2: then the on_Click event would change to open reports in the "Administration Reports" group.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have the first button set a state value / flag / field / variable, have the _On_Click for other buttons look at that state before deciding what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would use 3 main Toggle Buttons and put hem into an Option group frame (Let's call it FrameMain). Set the Option Value for the buttons as 1,2,3. Create as many regular buttons a you have sub topics (let's call them cmd1_1, cmd1_2, cmd2_1....) and set theirs property Visible to False and Tag to Sub. Now create event FrameMain_AfterUpdate:

```vb
Private Sub FrameMain_AfterUpdate()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Sub" Then
            ctl.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
    Select Case Me.FrameMain
        Case 1
            cmd1_1.Visible = True
            cmd1_2.Visible = True
        Case 2
            cmd2_1.Visible = True
            cmd2_2.Visible = True
        Case 3
            cmd3_1.Visible = True
            cmd3_2.Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can create now On_Click() event for all your sub-buttons to open the report you want.

You can also use a [Switch board](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/switchboard/index.php) (search the Internet how to create it).

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.